# encrypt file with SHA256 using C/C++

Tags: c, encryption, encode, sha256

How can I encode a file using sha256 and c/c++ ???
Thanks!

Comment: If you can `decrypt' a SHA256 hash, let me know P:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SHA 256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm#SHA-256) stands for Secure Hash Algorithm ! It will only produce the hash of a given file . You can't retrieve the original file from a given hash otherwise hash functions are useless.

If you want to do encryption/decryption [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) would be a better solution. Everything you need is in [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what SHA is for, then you better ask someone who knows this stuff instead of doing it yourself. Even if you use a given library, chances are very high that you will produce snake oil. Security depends on much more than calling some encryption functions.